# Trying to add a class to post links

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, css, count

I have a query looping through all posts in a custom post type using a custom order (via a re-ordering plugin.)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $current_id = get_the_ID();
    $counter = 0;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'course_unit',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order'
    ));
?>
        <h4>Your Course Units</h4>
        <ul>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-link<?php if($post_id == $current_id) : ?> current-unit<?php endif; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This output is this:

```
<h4>Your Course Units</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-1/" class="list-link">Unit 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-2/" class="list-link">Unit 2t</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-3/" class="list-link">Unit 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-4/" class="list-link">Unit 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-5/" class="list-link current-unit">Unit 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-6/" class="list-link">Unit 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-7/" class="list-link">Unit 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://website.com/unit-8/" class="list-link">Unit 8s</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I've attached a class to the current post so that the current course link in the list can have a special style. What I also want to do is have the styles prior to and after the current post be different. The user is supposed to go through the units one by one so I want the prior post links to be greyed out (all I need is a class and I can style it however.)

I tried to do this with a counter variable (because I can't do this with ids or date since it's a custom order) but I was unable to get it to work. How can I attach a class to all posts prior to the current one? Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of PHP can be used to determine if the current unit has been rendered or not.

In the solution below, the flag `$current_unit_rendered` is initially set to false. We check to see if we're on the current unit. If so, we set the `$unit_class` variable to the appropriate string and update the flag. Using this information, we know if we're before or after the current unit:

```
<?php
    $current_id            = get_the_ID();
    $current_unit_rendered = false;
    $unit_class            = '';
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Ideally, an upper limit like 500 should be used.
            'post_type'      => 'course_unit',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
    ) );
?>
<h4>Your Course Units</h4>
<ul>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ): while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        if ( get_the_ID() === $current_id ) {
            $unit_class = 'current-unit';
            $current_unit_rendered  = true;
        } elseif ( true === $current_unit_rendered ) {
            $unit_class = 'future-unit';
        } elseif ( false === $current_unit_rendered ) {
            $unit_class = 'previous-unit';
        }
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="list-link <?php echo esc_attr( $unit_class) ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Woohoo! You got it, @Alison!

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable to a classname before the loop:

```
$position = 'class-before';
```

Then reset it within the `if` condition:

```
if( $post_id == $current_id ) :
    ?> current-unit<?php
    $position = 'class-after';
endif;
```